# Advice on refactoring jQuery time duration calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am relatively new to jQuery and javascript in general; I'm knowledgeable enough to write basic scripts but I could do with some help optimising some of my code which to me does not seem efficient, but I don't know the best way to alter it.

I have two input type='time' form fields and a hidden form field which is used to hold the difference between the two fields.

Here is my code:

```
function timeDifference(field1, field2) {
    var field1val = $(field1).val();
    var field2val = $(field2).val();

    if ((field1val !== '--:--') && (field2val !== '--:--')) {           
        var hours = field1val.split(':')[0] - field2val.split(':')[0];
        var minutes = field1val.split(':')[1] - field2val.split(':')[1];

        minutes = minutes.toString().length<2?'0'+minutes:minutes;
        if(minutes<0){ 
        hours--;
        minutes = 60 + minutes;
        }
        hours = hours.toString().length<2?'0'+hours:hours;

        var difference = hours + ':' + minutes;
        return difference;          
    } else return false;
};

    $('#assessmentHeaderStartTime, #assessmentHeaderEndTime').change(function() {
    var duration = timeDifference('#assessmentHeaderStartTime','#assessmentHeaderEndTime');
    $('#assessmentHeaderDuration').val(duration);
    });
```

I am dubious that .change() is the best way to go about updating the duration value but I'm not sure what would be the optimal solution. I know input type='time' is not supported across all browsers but for now Chrome & Safari are our main focus which both support it.

I thought about maybe using .keyup() to only calculate the duration once the user has finished typing in a time, but Chrome & Safari both provide the option of clicking arrows to increase/decrease time so you can input data in a few ways. Plus I know this will be used on tablets and I'm not exactly sure whether the time dials they use to select times count as clicks or key presses.

It seems inefficient to call the function every time a change is made when users could, for example, click and hold the button to increase the minute counter from 01 to 59 and have it call the function at every interval in between as part of normal usage behaviour.

I don't know what the optimal solution to this would be. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that if you click the up arrow the `change` event is called?  From a quick test I ran it was not.

I was going to suggest using `onBlur` if the change event was firing too much, but it looks like the code you have will behave exactly how you want.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785099/what-is-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onchange-atrribute-in-html) question for more details on the difference between `onBlur` and `onChange`.

Comment: Yes I am sure it change fires on the up arrow. All 3 fields are on the same page and you can see the duration field update as you click the arrows to change the two other time fields. Thanks for the link but as you say it looks like the code I've got now best fits how I want it to behave.