# Change ASP Textbox Property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

So I have this ASP.NET form which contains TextBoxtA and TextBoxtB. I want that if I enter certain input on TextBoxA (for example '000') the TextBoxtB text value would be set to 'TextChanged' and disabled.

PS: And I want that happen right after the text di TextBoxA changes, not when onClick fired. So I use the attribute onTextChanged. According to this http://forums.asp.net/t/1300979.aspx, I have to use onChange instead and change the poperty on PageLoad on my code behind. But it can't seem to work.

So heres my code:

```
<script runat="server">
    function changeText() {
        var A = document.getElementById('<%=inputTexboxtA.ClientID%>').value;
        var B = document.getElementById('<%=inputTexboxtB.ClientID%>').value;

        if (A = '000') {
            B = 'TextChanged';
        }
    }
</script>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                inputTexboxtA.Attributes.Add("onChange", changeText());
            }

<asp:TextBox ID="inputTexboxtA" runat="server" MaxLength="3"/></td>
<asp:TextBox ID="inputTexboxtB" runat="server" MaxLength="3"/></td>
```

Am I doing it right? Thanks before!

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly no, you're doing it wrong. <strike>`OnChange` is not an event for text boxes.</strike>  Look at OnBlur for when the user changes field or `OnKeyUp` for when the user is typing for other options. Potentialy use both.

You may also want to investigate [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

You also have a syntax error and other problems. You need to use `==` or `!=` for comparison. Also you aren't change the value of `B` so:

```
function changeText() {
    var A = document.getElementById('<%=inputTexboxtA.ClientID%>').value;
    var B = document.getElementById('<%=inputTexboxtB.ClientID%>');

    if (A == '000') { // or (A != '000')
        B.value = 'TextChanged';
    }
}
```

OnBlur example: http://jsfiddle.net/4HwmU/

**Update: So I shouldn't code when tired! OnChange is fine the problem was the various errors in the code**

OnChange  Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/4HwmU/1/

For More info on the differnces between OnBLur and on Change: [What is the difference between onBlur and onChange attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785099/what-is-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onchange-atrribute-in-html)

Comment: @Jon-P sorry for the terrible syntax errors. No wonder I got a tons of errors. I'm using onKeyUp and it working well. Thanks a lot for the help! :D

Comment: @Rony the specs are a bit vague, so I mentioned both, I find blur less intrusive, but there are times the OnKeyUp is better, and I normaly use blur as a fallback with OnKeyUp, just in case.

Comment: @Jon P To my knowledge We can write javascript `onChange` event & for `asp.net textbox` there is `OnTextChanged`. pls refer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: @Pratik you are correct.... it's late in the day here and I've got `onchange` vs `onselect` back the front!

Comment: @paulfah don't forget to click the tick :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputTexboxtA.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", changeText());
        }
```