# When is the onchange event triggered in javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

Can someone explain to me when the onchange event is triggered in JS. Because I am making multiple drop-down lists where each one depends on the previous one's answer. But all the onchange events are firing, even though the selectItemIndex isn't changing...

Comment: code example would be good

Comment: `onchange` event is triggered on an element when its value changes. To help you, you need to show us your code (relevant portions).

Comment: Show some code please.  But I sounds like you are attaching the same event function to all the DDLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs when the actual `.value` changes, which doesn't officially occur until it loses focus. Can be the same as `onblur` event. Check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) page posted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785099/what-is-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onchange-attribute-in-html) question for more information on events.

Answer (score 0):

I found this

> The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been
>   changed.
>
> For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the onchange event occurs when the
>   checked state has been changed.
>
> Tip: This event is similar to the oninput event. The difference is
>   that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an
>   element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses
>   focus. The other difference is that the onchange event also works on
>   keygen and select elements.

you can see more here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

If you change the content of the dropdown you are also firing the onchange event.